# How to calculate a Differentiable Quotient?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is more than likely an Algebra problem but I can not figure out where the $-4x^2$ came from - first equation -3rd line.

I do see that they transferred the $2\sqrt{x}$ to the denominator. What made them take this strategy? Help welcomed so that I can understand.

[image]

Comment: In the second equation evaluate common denominator in the nominater. That's all.

Comment: What do you mean by "In the second equation evaluate common denominator in the nominator." Do you mean I should make sure each denominator in the numerator has 2 radical x?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify a compound fraction, rewrite the division by the overall denominator as multiplication by its reciprocal and start simplifying.

$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac1c =\frac{a}{bc}
$$
etc. In your specific case, $a,b,$ and $c$ are more complicated expressions, but this shows the general approach. This is how $b$ eventually appears in the denominator.

The simplifying of the numerator is another matter. Here, they use the fact that
$$\frac u{\boxed{v}} -\boxed{w}=\frac uv -\frac w1\cdot\frac vv=\frac uv-\frac{wv}v =\frac{u-\boxed{wv}}v
$$

Finally, note that $$\boxed{(2\sqrt{x})\cdot \sqrt{x}(2x)} =2\cdot2\cdot x\cdot\underbrace{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x}}_{x}=\boxed{4x^2}
$$

Comment: So from line 2 to 3, step by step, how was 4-x^2 attained?

Comment: Edited answer to show more